# php replace \n except where other valid HTML tags appear

Tags: php, regex

I am looking for a function that replaces \n stored in the db via user input into a textfield, except where there are already HTML tags in place. This is for a CMS, so that the dumbass users have less work to do.

So, for-instance, if the user wrote the following into the textfield:

```
<H1>Title of page</H1>

This is the first paragraph in the page.

<H2>Sub section</H2>

This is a sub-section.
```

I'd want the function to return:

```
<H1>Title of page</H1>

<p>This is the first paragraph in the page.</p>

<H2>Sub section</H2>

<p>This is a sub-section.</p>
```

Can anyone help with something they already have / have found?

Comment: Why not use a WYSIWYG editor like CKEditor?

Comment: Your question in title and content dont match?

Comment: If they know enough to put the `<h1>` and `<h2>` tags, why would they forget the `<p>` tags?

Comment: *"You can't make anything idiot-proof because idiots are so damn ingenious."*

Comment: Your best bet is to use an HTML Parser to figure it out. Regex will not solve this kind of complex problem.

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid reinventing the wheel, and you are probably going to run into a ton of special rules you have to handle.  Even in your question, the rules are unclear.  What does it have to do with \n?  I recommend using an html parser.  PHP has some:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($start);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$nodes = $xpath->query('//text()[following-sibling::* or preceding-sibling::*]');
foreach ($nodes as $node) {
   $parent = $node->parentNode;
   $p = $dom->createElement('p', htmlentities($node->nodeValue, ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
   $parent->insertBefore($p, $node);
   $parent->removeChild($node);
}
```

This will wrap all text nodes that are siblings of another node in `<p>`, including whitespace.  An important question is: are there ever text nodes with siblings that don't need to be wrapped?

Comment: I came across this looking for an alternative to PHP's crummy lookbehind support.  I just wonder if XPath can handle bbcode tags.